Changing the color of the title used with fncychap
I'm using the Lenny style with fncychap.  I want to change the color of the box and text at the top, which I have gotten mostly the way I want it.  It's just the upper left corner that is stubbornly remaining black.
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{\color{red}Research Theme}
\makeatother
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries\rm\selectfont\color{red}}
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{60}{62}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}


\end{document}



You need to set the color in a different place.
But, please, consider that in the chapter head you're mixing three different and visually incompatible fonts, namely Helvetica, Times and Computer Modern. And, no, Helvetica and Times aren't visually compatible, notwithstanding many people believe so.
And the overall shape of that chapter head is ugly.
Anyway…
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} % don't, please!
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Research Theme}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\parindent}{\color{chaptercolor}\parindent}{}{}
\makeatother
\colorlet{chaptercolor}{red!80}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}


\end{document}

At least, avoid pure red color…

Hint: any package that uses commands such as \rm that have been deprecated for 30 years should be considered for dumping.
